# Why does it shows View.as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django-views, django-templates

I'm not really sure where did it go wrong. I'm just a beginner in Django and I'm trying to create a  simple to-do list.
I want to directly call the logout if I click log out it'll go in the login.

urls.py

````
    from fileinput import nextfile
    from django.urls import path
    from .views import TaskList, TaskDetails, TaskCreate, TaskUpdate, DeleteView, CustomLoginView
    from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView
    urlpatterns  =[
        path('login/',CustomLoginView.as_view,name='login'),
        path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(next_page='login'),name='logout'), 
        path('', TaskList.as_view(),name='task'),
        path('task/<int:pk>/', TaskDetails.as_view(),name='task'),
        path('task-create/', TaskCreate.as_view(),name='task-create'),
        path('task-update/<int:pk>/', TaskUpdate.as_view(),name='task-update'),
        path('task-delete/<int:pk>/', DeleteView.as_view(),name='task-delete'),
    ]   
    ```
    
    task_list.html
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>{{request.user}}</p> <!--shows who is the current user with that task -->
        <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log me out</a>
    {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Ready to Login</a>
    {% endif %}
    <hr>
    <h1>My To Do List</h1>
    <a href="{% url 'task-create' %}"> Add Task</a>
    
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Items</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        {% for task in tasks %} 
        <tr>
            <td>{{task.title}}</td> 
            <td><a href="{% url 'task' task.id %}">View</a></td> 
            <td><a href="{% url 'task-update' task.id %}">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'task-delete' task.id %}">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        {% empty %}
        <h3>No Items in List</h3>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *call* the `.as_view(…)` method, so:

```
#                     call the method 🖟🖟
path('login/', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
```